# Best Vegetable for growing in pots?

Tags: vegetables, plant-recommendations, containers, container-gardening

I've grown a few different veg over the years including Tomatoes, Green Beans, Peppers, Sweetcorn and a few others. However, they are usually planted in the ground.

I'm looking at moving house later this year so ideally would want to take any plants I plant with me, so I would be looking at planting them in pots.

Are there any vegetables that grow well in pots, or are there any accommodations or changes I can make to allow the veg I mentioned above to grow in a pot without any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many plants are started in pots and sold that way to begin with.  I plant and grow tomatoes and peppers predominantly in pots, but see no reason why anything else wouldn't prosper that way as long as the environmental support is there.